# Solve the differential equation $x''+16x=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

It is required to solve the differential equation $x''+16x=0$ with two different techniques and see that the result is the same.

If we suppose the solution is of the form $x(t) = c e^{\lambda t}$, with $c \neq 0$, it is required to solve
$$\lambda^2 + 16 = 0 \longrightarrow \lambda = \pm 4i$$

Thus $x_1 = c_1 e^{(4i)t}$ and $x_2 = c_2 e^{(-4i)t}$ are solutions and the general solution is given by the sum as
$$x(t) = c_1 e^{(4i)t} + c_2 e^{(-4i)t} = (c_1 + c_2) cos(4t) + i(c_1-c_2)sin(4t), \quad (*)$$
where $c_1, c_2$ are complex numbers.

Then it is required to solve the same equation but with a different technique as follows:

Let $x' = y$. Thus $x'' = y' = -16x$. Then we get the system
$$\begin{pmatrix} x'\\ y'\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\ -16 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x\\ y\end{pmatrix}, \quad A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\ -16 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
where $p(\lambda) = det(A- \lambda Id) = \lambda^2+16 =0$ with solutions $\lambda = \pm 4i$.

Thus, the solution of the system
$$\begin{pmatrix} \alpha_1'\\ \alpha_2'\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 4i & 0\\ 0 & -4i \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \alpha_1\\ \alpha_2\end{pmatrix}, \quad \Lambda = \begin{pmatrix} 4i & 0\\ 0 & -4i \end{pmatrix}$$
is
$$\begin{pmatrix} \alpha_1\\ \alpha_2\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} c_1 e^{(4i)t}\\ c_2 e^{(-4i)t} \end{pmatrix}$$

Note that the eigenvector for $\lambda = 4i$ is
$$f = \begin{pmatrix} -i\\ 4\end{pmatrix}$$
and for $\lambda = -4i$ is
$$\bar{f} = \begin{pmatrix} i\\ 4\end{pmatrix}$$

Therefore, the desired solution for $(x, y)$ is
$$\begin{pmatrix} x\\ y\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} f & \bar{f} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} c_1 e^{(4i)t}\\ c_2 e^{(-4i)t} \end{pmatrix} = c_1 e^{(4i)t}f + c_2 e^{(-4i)t}\bar{f} = \begin{pmatrix} -ic_1 e^{(4i)t} + ic_2 e^{(-4i)t}\\ 4c_1 e^{(4i)t} + 4c_2 e^{(-4i)t}\end{pmatrix}$$

Note that
$$\frac{d}{dt}\begin{pmatrix} -ic_1 e^{(4i)t} + ic_2 e^{(-4i)t}\\ 4c_1 e^{(4i)t} + 4c_2 e^{(-4i)t}\end{pmatrix} - \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\ -16 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} -ic_1 e^{(4i)t} + ic_2 e^{(-4i)t}\\ 4c_1 e^{(4i)t} + 4c_2 e^{(-4i)t}\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 0\end{pmatrix}$$

Finally, we get that
$$x(t) = i(c_2-c_1)cos(4t)+(c_1+c_2)sin(4t), \quad (**)$$
where $c_1, c_2$ are complex numbers.

Why $(*)$ and $(**)$ are not equal?

EDIT 1 (problem found):

For the solution in the differential equation with $\Lambda$, we are picking the following initial conditions:
$$\begin{pmatrix} \alpha_1\\ \alpha_2\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} ic_1 e^{(4i)t}\\ -ic_2 e^{(-4i)t} \end{pmatrix}$$

Thus,
$$\begin{pmatrix} x\\ y\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} f & \bar{f} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} ic_1 e^{(4i)t}\\ -ic_2 e^{(-4i)t} \end{pmatrix} = ic_1 e^{(4i)t}f -ic_2 e^{(-4i)t}\bar{f} = \begin{pmatrix} c_1 e^{(4i)t} + c_2 e^{(-4i)t}\\ 4c_1 i e^{(4i)t} -4c_2 i e^{(-4i)t}\end{pmatrix}$$

This way, we get
$$x(t) = c_1 e^{(4i)t} + c_2 e^{(-4i)t} = (c_1 + c_2) cos(4t) + i(c_1-c_2)sin(4t), \quad (***)$$

Therefore, $(*)$ and $(***)$ are equal.

Comment: The exact arbitrary constants don't matter, you can absorb factors of $i$ and such and get other arbitrary constants. In this case $c_1^*+c_2^* = i(c_2^{**}-c_1^{**})$, etc

Comment: @NinadMunshi you were right! I wrote the solution. Thanks for the inspiration.